# Android Room - Issue displaying data from two tables in a Many to Many relationship using Adapters and recycle viewer

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-recyclerview, android-room

I currently have two classes Recipes and Ingredients, where a user inputs a recipe and ingredients to go with that recipe. I am ensuring every ingredient is unique to the database, therefore need a many to many relationship with my recipe and ingredients.

However my issue is that I am only able to display the values from my recipe class and when I print my ingredients it is empty...

Recipes class:

```
`@Entity(tableName = "recipe_table")
    public class Recipe {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public Integer recipeId;
    @NonNull
    public String title;
    @NonNull
    public String instructions;
    public Integer rating;
    
    public Recipe( @NonNull String title, @NonNull String instructions, Integer rating) {
        this.title = title;
        this.instructions = instructions;
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public Integer getId(){
        return recipeId;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public String getInstructions() {
        return instructions;
    }
    public Integer getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    }`
```

Ingredient Class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "ingredients_table")
public class Ingredients {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

    @NonNull
    public Integer ingredientId;
    @NonNull
    public String ingredients;


    public Ingredients(@NonNull String ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }

    public String getIngredients(){
        return ingredients;
    }

}
```

Classes to cross reference and get ingredients from recipes:

RecipeIngredientsRef class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "recipe_ingredients_table", primaryKeys = {"recipeId", "ingredientId"})
public class RecipeIngredientsRef {
    @ColumnInfo @NonNull
    public Integer ingredientId;
    @ColumnInfo @NonNull
    public Integer recipeId;
}
```

RecipeIngredientsJoin class:

```
public class RecipeIngredientsJoin{

    @Embedded public Recipe recipe;
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "recipeId",
            entityColumn =  "ingredientId",
            associateBy = @Junction(RecipeIngredientsRef.class)
    )
public List<Ingredients> ingredients;

    public List<Ingredients> getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }
}
```

And my DAO:

bothDAO:

```
@Dao
public interface bothDAO {

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT *, * FROM recipe_table INNER JOIN ingredients_table ON recipeId = ingredientId")
    public LiveData<List<RecipeIngredientsJoin>> getAllIngredientsFromRecipe();
```

I am using this DAO in order to display my items, please let me know if you need to see my database class to help solve the issue!

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you misuse many-to-many relations.
That query would be enough:

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM recipe_table") // <--- no need to JOIN, Room do it for you
// In addition, condition `INNER JOIN ingredients_table ON recipeId = ingredientId` is wrong, 
// since you're trying to match ingredients & recipes ids 
public LiveData<List<RecipeIngredientsJoin>> getAllIngredientsFromRecipe();
```

This method should return what you want. Of course for that `RecipeIngredientsRef` table should contain foreign keys both for recipes and ingredients.

Comment: As soon as I do this, I have the same issue, I am only able to get the value of my recipes inside my adapter class, rather than both recipes and ingredients. I am able to get the Ingredients[] return type which is empty :/

Comment: The only explanation to that is `RecipeIngredientsRef` table. Do you really have there rows holding foreign keys to `Recipe` and `Ingredients` tables?

Comment: It is shown is shown in my class above but here it is: Entity(tableName = "recipe_ingredients_table", primaryKeys = {"recipeId", "ingredientId"})
public class RecipeIngredientsRef {
    ColumnInfo NonNull
    public Integer ingredientId;
    ColumnInfo NonNull
    public Integer recipeId;
}

Comment: Yes, but have you inserted there rows? Let's say you have Recipe with `id` = 1 and Ingredient with `id` = 2. Have you inserted in `RecipeIngredientsRef` row with `recipeId` = 1 and `ingredientId` = 2? If you haven't - you should.